# How to open bashrc file from plesk server and add a new PHP PATH VERSION

Tags: command-line, plesk

I want to open my .bashrc file and and add a new PATH PHP VERSION `export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin:$PATH;`

In my root ssh connection i made : ls -a and i saw .bashrc ! but how i could open the file and add my new path ?

Sorry i'm really not a king in terms of command lines

Thanks a lot in advance if someone could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open file in editor you can use the following command:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Or you can just add the line without opening file in editor:

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin:$PATH;" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After editing the file, run the following command (it will apply changes):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Also, make sure that a `~/.profile` is there (sometimes it's missing). Otherwise, create it like this:

```
echo '[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc' > ~/.profile
```